# Display Recent Post on top PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to display recent post on top but its goes on the bottom of the previous post. Please tell me how do I display my recent post on the top.

here is my code for where post is submitted.

my_articles.php

```
<?php
include "db.php";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $post = $_POST ['articles'];
    header('Location: feed.php');
    $query = "INSERT INTO demo(articles)";

    $query .= "VALUES ('{$post}')";

    $create_post = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
}
?>
```

and this where I submit my post add_post.php

```
<?php 
include "db.php";
$query = "SELECT * FROM demo";
$select_all = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all)) {
    $text = $row['articles'];
    $date = $row ['time_min'];
?>

<p><?php echo $text ?></p>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `ORDER BY` clause. If you have an auto incrementing ID field,

`ORDER BY ID_FIELD DESC`

you could `ORDER BY` a date field but the logic is same if you use the ID field.

**Edit 1**

`SELECT * FROM demo ORDER BY ID_FIELD DESC`

**Edit 2**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM demo ORDER BY ID DESC";
```

Comment: can you share full method please. Yes I am using full ID with A_I

Comment: @WaqasAli check my edit.

Comment: where do I add this?

Comment: @WaqasAli in your query, but you should know that?

Comment: I am bit confused. please take a look at above codes. these are two files. if you can tell me the exact place I will be very thank full to you

Comment: @WaqasAli check **Edit 2**.

Comment: @WaqasAli could you be more specific? Are any errors thrown?

Comment: no any errors. when ever I submit text. it goes down to the previous post